# click a div and get the id of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to click on a element and get the id from another div which is not related to it.

I tried this:

```js
$(".map_flag").on("click",function(){
    var objective = ($(this).attr("data_modal"));

    $("#" + objective).fadeIn(300, function(){
        $("#" + objective).find(".modal_content").fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="map_flag" data_modal="map_1"> 
    <img src="img/image_1.png" alt="image one" >
</button>

<div id="map_1">
    <p class="modal_content">place holder</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you've having right now?

Comment: Looks fine, though there are no modal_content or modal_window elements

Comment: It gets the name of the data_modal fine, but it doesnt do the fade in.

Comment: I think I migth be making the reference ($("#" + objective)) wrong or something

Comment: the `#[elementName]` (jQuery mimics CSS selectors using `#` for IDs and `.` for classes, and so on...) is reserved for IDs of an element -- not data-* properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, custom attributes need to start off with `data-` not with `data_` (note the dash/underscore).

Then

```
$("#" + objective).fadeIn(300, function(){
    $("#" + objective).find(".modal_content").fadeIn(300);
});
```

first fades in `$('#map_1')` and then, after that's been done, fades in `$('#map_1 .modal')`. Not sure if that's intended, but if the `#map_1` elements has no further children, you might want to fade in only once.

For the rest, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need would be something like this:

```
<button class="map_flag" data-modal="map_1"> 
    <img src="img/image_1.png" alt="image one" >
</button>

<div id="map_1">
    <p class="modal_content">place holder</p>
</div>
```

And then in JavaScript

```
$(".map_flag").on("click",function(){

    // You should use data-* attributs as jQuery has a special function
    // .data("name") that obtains the value of property data-name for example
    var objective = $(this).data("modal");

    $("#" + objective).fadeIn(300, function(){
        $("#" + objective).find(".modal_content").fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, I changed your <button> code, I changed the data_modal to data-modal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very confident about my jquery skills, but dont you need to "fade out" before fade In ?
[https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_fadeout_fadein]

Comment: Well, that depends on the initial styles the element has. He hasn't shared his CSS, but I suppose he does have some.

Comment: There could be CSS that defaults it to hidden.

Comment: I agree, @Barmar

Comment: its set by display: none by default